# EA - Multi Currency Multi TimeFrame

Tags: mql4

I have a problem when I'm trying to find a way to check if a trade was made on the current bar or not to stop the EA for making multiple entries on the same bar.

When I don't do a multi Currency EA I usually just use

```
static datetime       lastTradeBar;
```

and

```
if(lastTradeBar!=Time[0])
{ 
if(PFTP_BuySignal   > 0 && PFTP_BuySignal_Prev  == 0 && PFTP_Rate > PFTP_Rate_Value)
  {
    myTP = PFTP_TP1;
    mySL = PFTP_BuySL;
    return (1);
  }
if(PFTP_SellSignal  > 0 && PFTP_SellSignal_Prev == 0 && PFTP_Rate > PFTP_Rate_Value)
  {
    myTP = PFTP_TP1;
    mySL = PFTP_SellSL;
    return (-1);
  }
else
    return (0);
    lastTradeBar=Time[0];
  };
return (0);
}
```

but this doesn't work when using it as I do now.
I'm thinking I need to make a myArray[sym,period,lastTradeBar] or myArray [sym][period][lastTradeBar]
but I can't wrap my head around how or where to put it.

this is the flow

1. int OnInit() ->
2. void OnTimer() ->
3. void LoopThruSym(stringlistOfSym) ->
4. void LoopThruPeriod(string sym, string listOfPeriods, int listOfSym) ->
5. void Trade(string sym, int period) ->
6. int Signal(string sym, int period)

This is how the flow is now.

```
 int OnInit()
  {
   EventSetTimer(5);
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }
```

....

```
void OnTimer()
  {
   LoopThruSym(symbols);
  }
```

....

```
void LoopThruSym(string listOfSym)
  {

   if(Mode == All)
     {
      int i;
      int numSymbolmarketWatch=SymbolsTotal(false);
      numSymbols=numSymbolmarketWatch;
      ArrayResize(symbolListFinal,numSymbolmarketWatch);
      for(i=0; i<numSymbolmarketWatch; i++)
        {
         symbolListFinal[i]=SymbolName(i,false);
        }
     }
   else
      if(Mode == Selected)
        {
         string sep=",";
         ushort u_sep;
         int i;
         u_sep=StringGetCharacter(sep,0);
         StringSplit(listOfSym,u_sep,symbolList);
         numSymbols=ArraySize(symbolList);
         ArrayResize(symbolListFinal,numSymbols);
         for(i=0; i<numSymbols; i++)
           {
            symbolListFinal[i]=symbolPrefix+symbolList[i]+symbolSuffix;
            LoopThruPeriod(symbolListFinal[i],periods, numSymbols);
           }
        }
      else
         if(Mode == Current)
           {
            LoopThruPeriod(Symbol(),periods,numSymbols);
           }

   return;

  }
```

....

```
 void LoopThruPeriod(string sym, string listOfPeriods, int listOfSym)
  {
   if(ModePeriod == All_Period)
     {
      string periodsALL      = "1,5,15,30,60,240,1440,10080,43200";
      string sep=",";
      ushort u_sep;
      int i;
      int lastTradeBarArrayCount;
      u_sep=StringGetCharacter(sep,0);
      StringSplit(periodsALL,u_sep,periodList);
      numPeriods=ArraySize(periodList);
      ArrayResize(periodListFinal,numPeriods);
      lastTradeBarArrayCount = listOfSym+numPeriods;
      ArrayResize(lastTradeBarArray,lastTradeBarArrayCount);
      for(i=0; i<numPeriods; i++)
        {
         periodListFinal[i]=symbolPrefix+periodList[i]+symbolSuffix;
         Trade(sym,StrToInteger(periodListFinal[i]));
         Comment("lastTradeBarArrayCount = "+lastTradeBarArrayCount);
        }

     }
   else
      if(ModePeriod == Selected_Period)
        {
         string sep=",";
         ushort u_sep;
         int i;
         int lastTradeBarArrayCount;
         u_sep=StringGetCharacter(sep,0);
         StringSplit(listOfPeriods,u_sep,periodList);
         numPeriods=ArraySize(periodList);
         ArrayResize(periodListFinal,numPeriods);
         lastTradeBarArrayCount = listOfSym*numPeriods;
        ArrayResize(lastTradeBarArray,lastTradeBarArrayCount);
         for(i=0; i<numPeriods; i++)
           {
            periodListFinal[i]=symbolPrefix+periodList[i]+symbolSuffix;
            Trade(sym,StrToInteger(periodListFinal[i]));
            Comment("lastTradeBarArrayCount = "+lastTradeBarArrayCount);
           }
        }
   if(ModePeriod == Current_Period)
     {
      Trade(sym,Period());
     }


  }
```

...

```
void Trade(string sym, int period)
  {
   //Print("Symbole = " + sym + " : " + period);
   if(OrderMethod == BuyandSell)
     {
      if(Signal(sym,period) == 1 && CheckMoneyForTrade(sym,Lots,OP_BUY) && CheckVolumeValue(sym,Lots))
         LimitBuy(sym,period);
      else
         if(Signal(sym,period) == -1 && CheckMoneyForTrade(sym,Lots,OP_SELL) && CheckVolumeValue(sym,Lots))
            LimitSell(sym,period);
     }
  else
   if(OrderMethod == BuyOnly)
     {
      if(Signal(sym,period) == 1 && CheckMoneyForTrade(sym,Lots,OP_BUY) && CheckVolumeValue(sym,Lots))
         LimitBuy(sym,period);
     }
   else
      if(OrderMethod == SellOnly)
        {
         if(Signal(sym,period) == -1 && CheckMoneyForTrade(sym,Lots,OP_SELL) && CheckVolumeValue(sym,Lots))
            LimitSell(sym,period);
        }
  //Trail(sym);

   return;
  }
```

...

```
int Signal(string sym, int period)
  {
  if(lastTradeBar!=Time[0])
    { 
    if(PFTP_BuySignal   > 0 && PFTP_BuySignal_Prev  == 0 && PFTP_Rate > PFTP_Rate_Value)
      {
        myTP = PFTP_TP1;
        mySL = PFTP_BuySL;
        return (1);
      }
    if(PFTP_SellSignal  > 0 && PFTP_SellSignal_Prev == 0 && PFTP_Rate > PFTP_Rate_Value)
      {
        myTP = PFTP_TP1;
        mySL = PFTP_SellSL;
        return (-1);
      }
    else
        return (0);
        lastTradeBar=Time[0];
      };
    return (0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code a function on the "void OnTick()" like this:

```
    void OnTick()
  {
//---
   CheckForSignal();
  }
```

And then code the function "CheckForSignal()"

```
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Function "CheckForSignal()"                                      |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void CheckForSignal(){
   //check here a bar until a Signal given Signal given then initialize it to Time[]
   static datetime candletime=0;
   if(candletime!=Time[0]){
      double upArrow=iCustom(your Custom indicator or whatever parameters);
      if(upArrow != EMPTY_VALUE){
         EnterTrade(OP_BUY);
      }
      double downArrow=iCustom(your Custom indicator or whatever parameters);
      if(downArrow != EMPTY_VALUE){
         EnterTrade(OP_SELL);
      }
      // if we have a Signal we will initialize candle time to Time[0] to avoid multiple Orders
      candletime=Time[0];
   }
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then Send Signal to Open or Close or whatever you need in my example we will open Trades

```
    //+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Function "EnterTrade()"                                          |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void EnterTrade(int type){

   int err=0;
   double price=0;
   double sl=0;
   double tp=0;
   
   if(type == OP_BUY){
      price=Ask;
   }else{
      price=Bid;
   }
   //steppoin8-step15: replace function "OrderSend" parameter
   //                  ->variablename "name" (magic)
   //steppoint8-step16: end ";"
   int ticket=OrderSend(Symbol(),type,LotSize,price,slippage,0,0,"EA Trade",magic,0,clrMagenta);
   

   if(ticket>0){         
      if(OrderSelect(ticket,SELECT_BY_TICKET)){
         if(OrderType()==OP_BUY){
            sl=OrderOpenPrice()-(stopLoss*pips);
            tp=OrderOpenPrice()+(takeProfit*pips);
         }else if(OrderType()==OP_SELL){
            sl= OrderOpenPrice()+(stopLoss*pips);
            tp= OrderOpenPrice()-(takeProfit*pips);
         }
         if(!OrderModify(ticket,price,sl,tp,0,clrMagenta)){
            err=GetLastError();
            Print("Encountered an error during modification!"+(string)err+" "+ErrorDescription(err));
         }
      }else{
         Print("Failed to Select Order",ticket);
         err=GetLastError();
         Print("Encountered an error while selecting order"+(string)ticket+" error number"+(string)err+" "+ErrorDescription(err));
      }
   }
   else{
      err=GetLastError();
      Print("Encountered an error during order placement"+(string)err+" "+ErrorDescription(err));
   }
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I feel like this would give me the same problem if I trigger this thru a loop. The candle time value changes state not only from one symbol but multiple symbols.

Comment: pls correct me if im wrong u need a code example where u trigger orders only once per signal not several times when ur indicator throws and buy or sell signal correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer more of like progress.
So what i'm doing not instead of checking for `candletime=Time[0]` I check then the last trade close time is for that sym/magic nr and comment. and then runing it thru `if(iBarShift(sym,period,OrderCloseTime()) > 1)`

this kinda works but I'm getting problems down the road if I'm trying to use symbols with different miniLots. But that will come on another post.

```
bool getLastOrderClose(string sym, int period)
  {
   if(OrdersHistoryTotal() == 0)
      return true;
   string comment    = "Multi Currency "+sym+":"+IntegerToString(period);
   int count = 0;
   int tradesPerSymbole =0;
   for(int i=OrdersHistoryTotal()-1; i >= 0; i--)
      if(OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_HISTORY))
        {
         if(OrderSymbol() == sym)
           {
            if(OrderMagicNumber() == Magic)
              {
               tradesPerSymbole++;
               if(StringFind(comment,OrderComment())<0)
                 {
                  if(iBarShift(sym,period,OrderCloseTime()) > 1)
                    {
                     return true;
                    }
                 }

              }

           }

        }
      else
        {
         Print(sym +" : "+"OrderSend() - getLastOrderClose - error - ", ErrorDescription(GetLastError()));
        }
   if(tradesPerSymbole == 0)
      return true;
   return false;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//OrderSend('EURUSD',blablabla Parameter)       
//OrderSend('GBPUSD',blablabla Parameter) 
//OrderSend('USDJPY',blablabla Parameter) 
//OrderSend('EURCHF',blablabla Parameter) 

int ticket=OrderSend('EURUSD',type,LotSize,price,slippage,0,0,"EA Trade",magic,0,clrMagenta);
   

   for(int I=ticket;ticket<Orderstotal();i++){         
      if(OrderSelect(ticket,SELECT_BY_TICKET)){
         if(OrderType()==OP_BUY){
            sl=OrderOpenPrice()-(stopLoss*pips);
            tp=OrderOpenPrice()+(takeProfit*pips);
         }else if(OrderType()==OP_SELL){
            sl= OrderOpenPrice()+(stopLoss*pips);
            tp= OrderOpenPrice()-(takeProfit*pips);
         }
         if(!OrderModify(ticket,price,sl,tp,0,clrMagenta)){
            err=GetLastError();
            Print("Encountered an error during modification!"+(string)err+" "+ErrorDescription(err));
         }
      }else{
         Print("Failed to Select Order",ticket);
         err=GetLastError();
         Print("Encountered an error while selecting order"+(string)ticket+" error number"+(string)err+" "+ErrorDescription(err));
      }
   }
   else{
      err=GetLastError();
      Print("Encountered an error during order placement"+(string)err+" "+ErrorDescription(err));
   }
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I think its not the pro solution but I would declare a Ordersend function for all the pairs where u want to open the order (I need not to say that the order send function should be declared in a conditional so only the the real ordersend be placed)

but the part where I want your attention is you can do it the hardware by declaring the Ordersend(not with Symbol() instead of that with "YourPairname");

hope this help you a little bit to reach your goal gl